# Add class to specific WordPress anchor menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating my custom bootstrap menu. However, I am stuck in something here. I want to add `class name` to only one of the `nav_menu`. For example:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Suppose, I want to add `class` in the `Contact` menu only. How it can be done? Adding `CSS Class` in the `Screen Options` will only add class to `<li>` iterm. But I want it in `<a>` tag.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: via jQuery you can try like : `$("a.btn").addClass("myClass");`

Comment: won't it add the same class to every anchor tag? Right now, there's no class named `btn` in my menu.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is paste the following code in your functions.php file:

```
//Filtering a Class in Navigation Menu Item
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    if($item->title == 'Contact'){
        $classes     = implode(' ', $item->classes);
        $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="'.$classes.'"', $item_output, 1);
        return $item_output;
    }
 }
add_filter('current-menu-item', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

The code above is simply checking the menu item title is Contact. If the criteria is matched, then it is adding a class “Current-menu-item”. We needed to add a custom class in order to make it work with this design that we are working on.

Comment: Hello Rahul, I think this code works same as `adding class` from `Screen options`. I placed the above code and it's displaying like this:

`<li class=" current-menu-item"><a title="Contact Us</a><Contact Us" href="http://localhost/aone/contact-us/">/li>`

but I want it as
`<li ><a class="current-menu-item" title="Contact Us</a><Contact Us" href="http://localhost/aone/contact-us/">/li>`

Comment: the classes are not added still :( . where's the class in the above ?

Comment: This solution is highly unreliable. In case of additional hooks, you will render class attribute twice and you will be prone to make inconsistencies during browser website rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **walker_nav_menu_start_el** filter to achieve something like that.

```
function add_class_to_menu_item($item_output, $item, $depth, $args)
{
    if( 51 == $item->ID ) {
        return str_replace('<a', '<a class="btn btn-primary"', $item_output);
    }
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_class_to_menu_item', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, hope is useful

```
  function anchor_menu_add_class( $atts, $item, $args) {
     if($item->title == 'Contact'){
    $class = 'nav-link btn btn-primary btn-sm px-2 py-1 mt-1 mr-2'; // your class
    $atts['class'] = $class;
  }
    return $atts;`enter code here`
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'anchor_menu_add_class', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score -1):

**First do one thing add class to your li with screen option like this**

```
<li class="contact"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</a></li>
```

then add this jquery.

```
$("ul li.contact").find('a').addClass("anchortagclass");
```

it will add class to your anchor tag for contact menu :)

Answer (score -1):

http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item

NO coding required, add classes as many you want, easy, fast, native WP.

Answer (score -1):

**You need to append a class attribute to the anchor itself. On your wordpress admin page**

Customize > Control Panel > scripts.

Add these to the text box.

```
<script>
var anchorarray = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<anchorarray.length; i++){
anchorarray[i].setAttribute('class', 'page-scroll');
}
</script>
```

this transalates as `class = page-scroll` you can change it to what you like.